# Introductory text book for Linear Recurrence Sequences

Tags: reference-request, exponential-polynomials

What is a good introductory text for linear recurrence sequences?

What all are the necessary prerequisite for it? (My background is in Euclidean Fourier Analysis.) After browsing through several books, my perception is one is supposed to know a fare bit of algebraic number theory , algebraic geometry, Diophantine Equations etc. (I am not sure if the subjects I mentioned are the only or even the appropriate areas, so please correct me if I am wrong) Is there a book which builds/gives the necessary material as it progresses.

I will appreciate any suggestion which you may think is going to be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to know about linear recurrences?  Most of their basic properties are summarized in the relevant chapters of Stanley's _Enumerative Combinatorics._

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thanks for the reference. I am interested in understanding the results related to zero multiplicity.

Comment: The book "Finite Fields", by Rudolf Lidl and Harald Niederreiter, contains a nice chapter on the linear recurring sequences.

Comment: I searched google and got Allen's thesis Multiplicites of Linear Recurrence Sequences.  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pballen/PAllen_MMath_Thesis.pdf


Comment: @sandeepj it really looks interesting! thank you.